# how to fit html form to fill container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container separated in two sides. On left side there is a slider, and on right side there is a html form for input. My problem is that I can't make the html form have the same height as slider on all pc monitors(it is usually shorter in height than the slider.
Can sb pls help me achieve this?

Comment: show your code how you are trying!

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please provide what you have tried and where you have failed!

Answer (score 1):

Use flex on the container div that contains the sidebar and the form.

```css
html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.con{
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  display:flex;
}
.side{
  width:100px;
  background-color:red;
}
form{
  background-color:yellow;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="con">
  <div class="side">
    this is the sidebar
  </div>
  <form>
    form contains the input
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm making a code for you. please check below link:

https://jsfiddle.net/fatehjagdeo/sqxy4pv6/

or also you can check my code below. this code will get height from your slider and add into your form div:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="leftside">
you slider here
</div>

<div class="rightside">
your form
</div>
</div>

<style>
.leftside{
  background:#ccc;
  height:200px;
}
.rightside{
  background:#ff0000;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var sliderHeight=$('.leftside').height();
$('.rightside').css('height',sliderHeight);
})
</script>
```

Comment: Actually the right and left divs are on equal height but the form is not filling entire height of div

Comment: ok, then you can add margin or padding to your form elements according to your slider by calculate the height of slider with jQuery